# AngularJS private function unit testing confusion

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I have read a couple articles and SO questions, but am still a little fuzzy on what I can and can't unit test.

I have a directive which returns a controller that has a couple of functions.  Some of these functions have return statements, and others don't.  I can see in the code coverage report that all of the functions are available to test, but only the functions with return statements are covered.  Is it possible to unit test the controller's functions that don't have return statements?  If yes, then how would I go about doing so?

**directive.js** snippet

```
app.directive('directive', function() {
    var theController = ['$scope', function($scope) {
        $scope.add = function() {
            // no return statement, not covered, but is available
        };

        $scope.disableAddButton = function() {
            // has a return statement and is fully covered
        };
    }];

    return: {
        scope: {
            args: '='
        },
        templateUrl: ...,
        restrict: 'A',
        controller: theController
    };
});
```

**directive.spec.js**

```
describe('The directive', function() {
    var element,
        $scope,
        controller;

    beforeEach(module('app'));
    beforeEach(module('path/to/template.html'));

    beforeEach(inject(function($compile, $controller, $rootScope, $templateCache) {
        template = $templateCache.get('path/to/template.html');
        $templateCache.put('path/to/template.html', template);
        $scope = $rootScope;
        controller = $controller;
        var elm = angular.element('<div directive></div>');
        element = $compile(elm)($scope);
        $scope.$digest();
        theController = element.controller('directive', {
            $scope: $scope
        });
    }));

    it('should compile', function() {
        expect(element.html()).not.toBeNull();
    });

    describe('$scope.add', function() {
        beforeEach(inject(function() {
            add = theController.add();
        }));

        it('should be defined', function() {
            expect(add).toBeDefined(); // passes
        });

        // Now what???
    });
});
```

Comment: Add should actually do something, presumably. Once you've run add, is there a change in the data that you can look at to make sure that something was added somewhere?

Comment: Yes, I can do that.  Right now the problem is making the controller available in the test.

Comment: You already have it available in the test, since your test passes. But your question was not about how to get hold of the controller.

Comment: Correct.  It was a question about how to get hold of its functions, which I can't seem to do.  Maybe it's a bad test.  I'm asserting that the controller function should be defined.  Maybe that's why those tests are failing...

Comment: In the test the controller is defined but none if its functions are.  Even `spyOn(theController, 'add');` is giving me `add() is not a method`.

Comment: You should maybe ask that question instead of what you did ask. BTW, if you want to check that theController.add is defined, you should set add to theController.add, not theController.add(). Also, instead of looking on theController, try looking on $scope. When you run $compile on your html, it should create the controller on the scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "unit" you're testing is the entire directive/controller, not individual functions.  Rather than trying to test each function in isolation, test that the results of calling the function are what you expect.

For example, what does `add` do?  Presumably it has an effect on something - ensure that that has taken place.

Your title also mentions private functions.  These are what the implementor of the "unit" has decided are necessary to get their job done.  They aren't part of the public interface of the object, so you shouldn't need to worry about testing them - just ensure that the unit does what it's public interface says it should do - there could be any number of private functions actually doing that work.

Comment: That makes sense.  I'm guessing the same goes if the private functions have anonymous functions?

Comment: Yes - anything that's internal to the class/object/controller (whatever it is that defines the entire "unit" you're testing) is not something that's testable directly.  Whilst you should try to ensure that your tests cover all the code within it, you're not able to call them directly and should just concentrate on the public effects of using the public interface.

Comment: I haven't been able to test `theController` directly.  Is that possible?  I thought it was since it's in the return statement.  I'm looking at [Vojta Jina's](https://github.com/vojtajina/ng-directive-testing/blob/master/test/tabsSpec.js) example, but he declares his controller globally, outside of the directive.

Comment: You can test theController directly by initializing it as a controller without doing the whole $compile thing.